# Save Button not showing up when i try to add my custom app in Micrsoft TEAMS channel as a new TAB

Tags: tabs, microsoft-teams, custom-application

i want to add my custom app to microsoft team channel as a new tab, when i click on plus sign to add  a new tab window opens with several app, i can see my app also there, but after wards when i click on it new window opens but on there the save option is grayed out, so i am not able to add, can any one please suggest anything here.
Adding a Teams App as Custom app
[image]

Save Button has been diabled.
[image: save button disabled]
i need my custom app to be added as teams channel tab.

Thanks In advance...

Comment: Are you calling [microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/configuration-page) to enable Save button?

Comment: I did not have any configuration page itself, i was not using any microsoftTeams library, i was able to add it as an app with manifest file, 
But later came to know that to add it as a teams tab i will have to have microsoftTeams  library in my angular app then some how have this microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true) , i some how managed to call it, now save button is enabled but on clicking t shows error that "We are not able to save your tab details"

Comment: @ASR Could you please check if you have specified all the url's properly in your configuration page?

Answer (score 0):

Your page should have a script section like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/sdk/v1.6.0/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js"></script>
<script>
    microsoftTeams.initialize();
    microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true);
</script>
```